# upgrade asp.net core targeting framework 4.6.1 from vs2015 to vs2017 - One or more compilation references are missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have upgraded my asp.net core,using project.json and targeting .net framework 4.6.1 on visual studio 2015 to visual studio 2017.

I have multiple projects in the solution where the main application is referencing them by project reference(all of them target net461).

When running the application I get

> One or more compilation references are missing. Possible causes
>   include a missing 'preserveCompilationContext' property under
>   'buildOptions' in the application's project.json.

screenshot:
[image]

I have tried adding the     true
to all of the reference projects without luck.

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to implement ASP.NET Identity into an existing site? What aspnet core version are you attempting. The generated version is 1.0.1. I have found that you need to play around with the other libraries. The fact that it states project.json, which isn't in the new aspnet core tells me something. Also are you using the razor engine? or did you replace it with view engine?

Answer (score 1):

Look in your Login.cshtml file and ensure you give the fully qualified name to the model to find your LoginViewModel and inject your SignInManager.  Something like this:

@model company.Web.Models.AccountViewModels.LoginViewModel

@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager SignInManager

That should allow the view to serve the page correctly.

Comment: You might only need to put a `@using mynamespace` of the class that you are using which is being reference at the top of your CSHTML page or in your _ViewImports.cshtml page.